# A HTML code which is clickable and connected to excel spreadsheet

Tags: html, excel

Is there any HTML code clickable and connected to my spreadsheet on my PC when I post this gadget on my website, by clicking on it, the data from my website will be exported on a cell in my excel spraedsheet? 
Assume, I fill for example 5 numbers in the gadget on my website then I want to have by clicking on each number, get this number on my excel spraedsheet in my PC.

Comment: Have you done any research yourself before posting this question?

Comment: html no, you might be able to achieve it with java script depending on the accessibility of your excel file. https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-javascript-programming-overview?product=excel